# Multiple AND / OR inside my list views filters using the UI, what is the correct way to apply them?

Tags: list, development, list-view, caml, sharepoint-library

I want to build a list view which have the following Filter criteria-

```
“Item Status != close” AND “Item status !=reject” AND 
(
(“Type= Team”)
OR
(“Type=IT” AND “Approved=True” And “Escalated=True”)
)
```

So in other words I want the items which are not close and are not reject at the first place. Then to do extra filters and to view the items that have its type=Team , OR its type=IT & it is approved and escalated.

Now not sure how I can apply this inside my list filters ? as I need inner OR and inner AND , as mentioned in my brackets ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some 3rd party tools which may allow multiple conditions in a list. If your wish is to avoid them, you should create a couple of calculated columns to your list.

Calculated column 1: `AND("Item Status"!="close", "Item Status"!="reject")`

Calculated column 2: `AND("Type"="IT", "Approved"=true, "Escalated"=true)`

Calculated column 3: `OR("Calculated column 2"=true, "Type"="Team")`

Then on the list view's filters use the Calculated column 1 AND Calculated column 3.

I haven't tried this, but this should give you the logic.

Comment: so is it a standard way to use calculated columns to use them inside view filters ? now your appraoch sound valid , but i need to test it first. second point i read that i can modify the view using sharepoint designer and manually update the related CAML query ? what do you think about this appraoch ?and not sure if i manually update the view using sharepoint designer will i be able to update it later on using the UI ?

Comment: There really isn't any standard for this scenario, but CAML is also an option. There's a related question which should provide the CAML way to do: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171798/caml-query-for-filtering-list-view. I have no experience of that, so can't tell how SharePoint's list view settings function after a direct change to the CAML.